# Different ways to do a precomputed truth check

Tags: c, arrays

I am working on a program which generates C code for one function. This generated C function resides in the central loop of another target program; this function is performance sensitive. The generated function is used to call another function, based on a bool value -- this boolean value is fetched using 2 ints passed to the generated function: a state number and a mode number. Generated function looks like so:

```
void dispatch(System* system, int state, int mode) {
    // Some other code here...
    if (truthTable[state][mode]) {
        doExpensiveCall(system, state, mode);
    }
}
```

Some facts:

- The range of 'state' and 'mode' values start at 0, and end at some number < 10,000. Their possible values are sequential, with no gaps in between. So, for example, if the end value of 'state' is 1000, then we know that there are 1001 and states (including state 0).
- The code generator is aware of the states and modes, and it knows ahead of time which combination of state+mode will yield a value of true. Theoretically, any combination of state+mode could yield true value, and thus make a call to doExpensiveCall, but in practive it will mostly be a handful of state+mode combinations that will yield a value of true. Again, this info is known during the code generation.
- Since this function will be called alot, I want to optimize the check for the truth value. In the average case, I expect the test to yield false for the vast percetage of time. On average, I expect that less than 1% of the calls will yield a value of true. But, *theoretically*, it could be as hight as 100% of the time (this point depends on the end-user).

I am exploring the different ways that I could compute whether a state+mode will yied a call to doExpensiveCall(). In the end, I'll have to choose something, so I'm exploring my options now. These are the different ways that I could think of so far:

1) Create a precomputed dual dimensional array, which contains booleans. This is what I'm using in the example above. This yields the fastest possible check that I can think of. The problem is that if state and mode have large ranges (say 10,000x1000), the generated table starts becomming very big (in the case of 10,000x1000, thats 10MB for just that table). Example:

```
// STATE_COUNT=4, MODE_COUNT=3
static const char truthTable[STATE_COUNT][MODE_COUNT] = {
  {0,1,0},
  {0,0,0},
  {1,1,0},
  {0,0,1}
}
```

2) Create a table like #1, but compressed: instead of each array entry being a single boolean, it would be a char bitfield. Then, during the check, I would do some computation with state+mode to decide how to index into the array. This reduces the size of the precomputed table by MODE_MODE/8. The downside is that the reduction is not that much, and now theres is now need compute the index of the boolean in the bitfield table, instead of just a simple array access as in the case in #1.

3) Since the amount of state+mode combinations that will yield a value of true is expected to be small, a switch statement is also possible (using the truthTable in #1 as reference):

```
switch(state){
case 0: // row
 switch(mode){ // col
  case 1: doExpensiveCall(system, state, mode);
  break;
 }
break;
case 2:
 switch(mode){
    case 0:
    case 1: doExpensiveCall(system, state, mode);
    break;
 }
break;
case 3:
 switch(mode){
    case 2: doExpensiveCall(system, state, mode);
    break;
 }
break;
}
```

QUESTION:

**What are other ways that, given the facts above, can be used calcuate this boolean value needed to call doExpensiveCall()?**

Thanks

Edit:
I though about Jens sample code, and the following occurred to me. In order to have just one switch statement, I can do this computation in the generated code:

```
// #if STATE_COUNT > MODE_COUNT
int i = s * STATE_COUNT + m;
// #else 
int i = m * MODE_COUNT + s;
// #endif

switch(i) {
case 1: // use computed values here, too.
case 8:
case 9:
case 14:
     doExpensiveCall(system, s, m);
```

}

Comment: Have you tried profiling/benchmarking anything to see if it matters? All things being equal, I would start with the simplest solution (#1) and see if there was any point in optmizing things first.

Comment: A hash table with a perfect hash function?

Comment: Optimization also depends on what is important in your case: speed, memory, simplicity/future maintenance etc....

Comment: I am asking what are the different ways that this can be accomplished, not which one is faster. I listed 3 approaches, and I'm hoping to get other suggestions. Once I've compiled the list of approaches, I'll start doing the benchmarking to arrive at the final solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to use a modified version of (3), where you actually have only one call, and all the `switch/case` stuff leads to that call. By that you can ensure that the compiler will choose whatever heuristics he has for optimizing this.

Something along the line of

```
switch(state) {
 default: return;
 case 0: // row
   switch(mode){ // col
   default: return;
   case 1: break;
   }
   break;
 case 2:
   switch(mode){
   default: return;
   case 0: break;
   case 1: break;
   }
   break;
 case 3:
   switch(mode){
   default: return;
   case 2: break;
   }
   break;
 }

doExpensiveCall(system, state, mode);
```

That is, you'd only have "control" inside the `switch`. The compiler should be able to sort this out nicely.

These heuristics will probably be different between architectures and compilation options (e.g `-O3` versus `-Os`) but this is what compilers are for, make choices based on platform specific knowledge.

And for your reference to time effeciency, if your function call is really expensive as you claim, this part will just be burried in the noise, don't worry about it. (Or otherwise benchmark your code to be sure.)

Comment: "where you actually have only one call, and all the switch/case stuff leads to that call." Could you show some sample code? I'm interested to know how you'd go about this.

Answer (score 0):

If the code generator knows the percentage of the table that's in use it can choose the algorithm at build time.

So if it is about 50% true/false use the 10 MB table.

Otherwise use a hash table or a radix tree.

A hash table would choose a hash function and a number of buckets. You'd compute the hash, find the bucket and search the chain for the true (or false) values.

The radix tree would choose a radix (like 10) and you'd have 10 entries with pointers to NULL (no true values down there) and one would have a pointer to another 10 entries, until you finally reach a value.